# Local DNS issue, conflicting between domain controller IP address and website IP Address

Tags: dns, rds

Some how when I try to access the company website directly from our network, it redirects to the domain controller IP address, instead of the company website.
If I delete the host A record and added another record with the website IP address, works for a couple of days but then the host A record from the DC Ip address comes back as same as parent folder.

[image]

Comment: so your website uses the same name as your internal MS domains root name?

Comment: that is correct. when I go to https://adoptabsc.org it takes me to IIS site. instead of the actually website, and when I go to the internal DNS server, I see below.
(same as parent folder) Host (A) 10.0.0.13 
(same as parent folder) Host (A) 151.101..33.134
So when I delete the first entry and do flushdns everything works fine but then the same entry gets recreated automatically and it stop working

Answer (score 1):

So this is a good reason why organizations use `www.domain.org` for their website front-ends.

I'm far from an expert on AD, but I do believe that your MS domain client systems will require the domain name for the root of the domain to point to the domain controllers.

As such, you are kind of starting out in a hole dug by past administrative decisions.

My recommendation, is that you add a binding for your website (using MS terminology here) to add the www name, create an A-rec for www pointing to your webservers private IP in your AD DNS servers zone, and have your internal users use [www.adoptabsc.org](http://www.adoptabsc.org) to reach your website. This may require you to regenerate your HTTPS certificate to include the additional www subdomain.

Then on your public DNS server (or host if your registrar hosts your domain), create a CNAME rec pointing [www.adoptabsc.org](http://www.adoptabsc.org) to adoptabsc.org, so that the public in general can see your site by using either name. your public DNS server should NOT be your MS AD domain controller.

that will leave you with the public being able to view your site using either name, and your internal users using www. best proposal I can offer, unless you are willing to change fundamental things like your websites public name. This would be a much cleaner solution if you were able to change your public website name to [www.adoptabsc.org](http://www.adoptabsc.org).

Comment: It's also why organizations use `ad.example.com` as the root of their AD domain...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a `ipconfig /flushdns` on DC, also if you have any reverse proxy manager such as Nginx manager check the settings there